# Disable system level shortcuts in OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-mavericks, slate

I am having trouble with using [Slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate) on OS X Mavericks. I've configured a <kbd>Hyper</kbd> key with KeyRemap4MacBook and want to use the Slate window manager to bind <kbd>Hyper</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to a certain window movement like this:

```
bind .:${hyper} ${rightbottom}
```

Whenever I press this key combination, the system performs a system diagnose, which, according to [this manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/perfdiagnose.1.html), is apparently bound to this key combination. I've looked all over the internet, but I can't find how to disable this built in functionality (it is not in System Preferences). Does anyone know how to fix this, or where to look?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with KeyRemap4macbook, basically you bind <kbd>Hyper</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>
to an unused key like <kbd>F18</kbd> then in your `.slate` use `f18` for that
action. The code for your `private.xml` is like this:

```html
<item>
    <name>Change Hyper+dot to F18</name>
    <appendix>Changing Hyper+dot because OSX steals the key</appendix>
    <identifier>private.hyper_dot</identifier>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::DOT,
      ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,

      KeyCode::F18
    </autogen>
</item>
```

Of course if you have multiple remaps in the `private.xml` you need to wrap them in
`<root>` tag.